# how can I parse this JSON into several 'objects'?

Tags: javascript, json, deserialization

I have an object defined like this:

```
function Question_Value__c () {
    this.Id=null;
    this.Name=null;
    this.Question__c=null;
    this.Order__c=null;
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON into several of these objects but I can't get it to work:

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;ee&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;ee&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;ee&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;ee&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;ee&quot;}]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
allValues = new Array(new Question_Value__c());
$(returnedJSON).each(function() {
    allValues.push($(this));
console.log(allValues[0].id);
});
```

Any assistance is much appreciated, I'm pretty new to working with JSON and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to put actual `"` in your JSON string, it is not valid to encode these caracters using `&quot;`, that would be in HTML however.

In addition, if you want to populate your `Question_Value_c` objects with data, you should change your constructor function to something like:

```
   function Question_Value__c(data) {
       $.extend(this, data); //have a look at $.extend
   }
```

Then you could do that (note that your objects do not have `Question__c` and `Order__c` properties):

```
  var json = '[{"id":"a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX","name":"ee"},{"id":"a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX","name":"ee"},{"id":"a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX","name":"ee"},{"id":"a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX","name":"ee"},{"id":"a0Dd000000RTVsAEAX","name":"ee"}]',
       allValues = [];

   $.each($.parseJSON(json), (function () {
       allValues.push(new Question_Value__c(this));
   }));

   console.log(allValues);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the core issue was the quotes. I ended up converting it to a string replacing the &quot; with " and then parsing it as JSON.